# having issues figuring out if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement

i need to figure out how to add an if..elseif..elseif statement to play different sound files based on the user input value

```
disp('Press A to play automatic speech program')
disp('Press any other key to manually control what to say')
input('Enter your selection:')

disp('1 - Check out whats new    5 - Irritate me         9 - Game show buzzer')
disp('2 - PacMan death           6 - About time         10 - The price is wrong') 
disp('3 - Buy one get one free   7 - Hard drive crash   11 - Final Countdown')
disp('4 - Hasta la vista         8 - Ms Pacman death    12 - Goodbye')


disp('Press 12 to say goodbye or enter the voice number to play a voice:')

if 1
    [y,Fs] = audioread('check_out_whats_new.wav');
    sound(y,Fs)
end

if 2
    [y,Fs] = audioread('pacman_death.wav');
    sound(y,Fs)
end
```

Comment: note that `if 1` and `if 2` are ALWAYS true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a switch-statement to do this:

```
selection = input('Enter your selection:');

switch selection
    case 1
        [y,Fs] = audioread('check_out_whats_new.wav');
        sound(y,Fs)
    case 2
        [y,Fs] = audioread('pacman_death.wav');
        sound(y,Fs)
    % ...
end
```

To answer your question directly, here is how the if-elseif-statement looks like:

```
selection = input('Enter your selection:');

if selection == 1
    [y,Fs] = audioread('check_out_whats_new.wav');
    sound(y,Fs)
elseif selection == 2
    [y,Fs] = audioread('pacman_death.wav');
    sound(y,Fs)
end
```

---

Addressing the question in the comment, this can be achieved by using a while-statement with a variable to be able to exit if needed. The following code does that:

```
repeat = true;
while repeat
    sel = input('Enter your selection:','s');

    switch str2double(sel)
        case 1
            [y,Fs] = audioread('check_out_whats_new.wav');
            sound(y,Fs);
        case 2
            [y,Fs] = audioread('pacman_death.wav');
            sound(y,Fs);
        % ... more cases
        case 12
            repeat = false;     % exit the while-statement
        otherwise
            disp('no valid input');
    end

end
```

Note that I added some extra handling as well. The `'s'` as second argument of `input` returns a string representation of the user-input. With `str2double` we can convert the string to a number and then use the switch as before. For `case 12` you set `repeat` to `false` which will exit the while-statement in the next iteration. If the user-input does not match a case, it will ask again for an input. Use `otherwise` to display a message in this case.

Comment: can i use this function for 12 cases? and keep them playing one after the other ?

Comment: Both solutions can be extended

Comment: Yes, both solutions can be extended to more cases as @Daniel said already.

Comment: when i run the section the first selection i make does not run only the second one then it stops, how do i make it so i can keep entering selections and have it play

Comment: @JoseGarcia I added a part to address this question as well. Please consider upvoting my answer if you like it. ;)

Comment: how do i add a round() function call to round the user input to the nearest integer “between” the input()
function call and the if..elseif..elseif….else statement to handle inputs like 1.1, 1.9, and etc

Comment: @JoseGarcia Change the line with the switch-statement to `switch round(str2double(sel))`. If it should be a separate line, just do `sel=str2double(sel);`, next line `sel=round(sel);` and then `switch sel`...

Comment: how do i make a counter display how many sound files were played?

Comment: Set a variable to 0 before the while-statement. Increase it by one just before the switch inside the while-statement. Decrease it by one in `otherwise` since this is the only path in case nothing played. In case of further questions not regaring the original question about if-elseif-statements, please ask a new question instead of continuing here in the comments.